# Mercurial disable auto-push for commit

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using TortoiseHG/Mercurial and i set up my local repository to automatically push to the "default" server-repository path after each commit. Ok, that works so far. But for certain merges, I want to disable that auto push. When I merge two revisions in my local repo, a dialog appears where the option `--pushafter=default` is listed. I then can disable that option for this commit. But it does not have an effect. The changesets will always be pushed to the server repo. What am I doing wrong?

I am a bit confused because I think this already worked some time ago. I could merge two revisions, do some tests, and if they failed I could roll back my local repo, do bugfixes, merge again. And when everything was ok i pushed to the server repo. Now, I can not roll back my local repo after a merge, because the merge commit will always be pushed to the server. I could only roll back the push-response, which is not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Christian